# Hide dot files using ftp with Windows Explorer (Linux backend)

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ftp, dotfiles

The company who I used to host my websites with has just been sold to another (site5.com), and my websites have been migrated.

With the original company, if one was to view a remote directory using ftp **with Windows Explorer**, any 'dot files' were hidden from view, but with site5's set-up, they are visible.

Their tech support is pretty hopeless imho, and in the last exchange on this problem they say it's impossible (which it obviously isn't).

Can someone explain to me how this probably worked with the old company (I can't ask them directly anymore) so that I can relay on the necessary information please.

Comment: It might be important to understand FTP Server specifics such as what FTP server are they using and what version perhaps? It may be that the FTP service you connected to on the old pre-migration server had its configurations setup accordingly whereas whatever they are using they haven't configured this accordingly or perhaps their FTP server service lacks such functionality. I'm not sure if a Linux `chmod 600` would help or cause further problems but allowing only the owner of those dot files to read it may be a simple thing to test otherwise find out FTP server service details & include that.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain to me how this probably worked with the old company[?]

At a guess, they probably used FTP software that allowed files beginning with `.` to be excluded from the list files returned by the server.

However (as far as I am aware) there is nothing in any FTP specification that mandates this behavior. Furthermore, I am certain there are at least some pieces of FTP server software that provide no option for this kind of behavior at all.

**But Linux...!**

While it may be possible to change permissions in such a way as to prevent certain users from viewing/interacting with certain files, depending on a number of factors, this could cause issues your provider may be unwilling to deal with.

In short, when they say it's "impossible", from a practical standpoint on their end, they may be correct.

**Security Vs. Clutter**

- If you are worried about "hidden" files being displayed for security reasons, you may simply have to rethink your websites' layout or move to another provider.
- If it's just a matter of clutter, certain FTP clients (such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)) can filter files starting with e.g. `.` or similar.